# Is there a way to target element by its tag type with an attr selector?

Tags: css, attributes

Recently the warning policy where I work changed, so now styles with tag type are forbidden somehow. Like this:

```
p{somestyle}
```

This causes huge amounts of stylesheets to become wrong.
My question is, can you target an element by its tag type using attribute selectors? Something like:

```
[tagType=p].someclass{somestyle}
```

Comment: Then you tell your boss you need a few weeks to update all style sheets for the existing sites..., as there is nothing gained by doing what you suggest, adding classes would be though.

Comment: I'm wondering if I understand the question. Isn't `p.someclass{somestyle}` what you need?

Comment: it is solved now, but what I needed by then was a workaround for that. I couldn't use `p.someclass`, so I was looking for something like `[elemType=p].someclass`, in a similar way that you can do with the other attributes, like `[id=someID].someclass` which would be the same as `#someID.someclass`. Sorry if I made a poor explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**No of course.** There are no any reasons to use other type of selector for tag name except tag name itself. Actually the only such thing could've been selector priorities, but there are usually no reasons to enlarge priority of tag-only selectors.

Actually you can try something like `:matches` (`:-moz-any`, `-webkit-any`) pseudoclasses, but **the right way is to keep tag selectors as the are**.